# Sqlalchemy session.query result doesn't have column name

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
        all_hero = db.session.query(HeroModel.hero_metadata_id, HeroModel.enchant_level, HeroModel.is_evolve,
                                HeroModel.skill_1_level, HeroModel.skill_2_level, HeroModel.skill_3_level,
                                HeroModel.equipment_id_accessory, HeroModel.equipment_id_weapon,
                                HeroModel.soul_stone, HeroModel.state).\
        filter(HeroModel.id.in_(hero_ids)). \
        all()
```

I cannot access all_hero with attribute such as 'all_hero.state'

and also result is printed like this
    {
    "hero": [
        [

```
       0: 1,
       1: 0,
       2: false,
```

...

I want the result to be

'hero_metadata_id':1,

'hero_enchant_level: 0

....

help me...

Answer (score 0):

You are providing a list of columns to query against, so SQLAlchemy is responding by returning a list of columns. You should just query the `HeroModel` entity if you want object access to your attributes.

```
# returns a list of model instances matching the ids in hero_ids
all_hero = db.session.query(HeroModel).\
        filter(HeroModel.id.in_(hero_ids)). \
        all()

# access attributes on the model instances
for hero_instance in all_hero:
    print(hero_instance.hero_metadata_id)
```